# Expectation of an integral of an arbitrary stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am looking to get some ideas on what this means

$\Bbb E[\int_0^T\sigma_tdW_t]=0$ where $\sigma_t$ is an arbitrary process and $W_t$ is the standard Brownian motion.

the text I am reading seems to take this for granted but I am trying to get my head around.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If $\sigma_t$ is adapted to the filtration and it's square integrable with respect to the product measure $P\otimes \lambda$ then this is an Ito integral and it has $0$ mean

Comment: For the non-adapted case you should consider it as a Skorkhod integral

Comment: Thanks Chaos! Found the parts on Ito integral properties on my old lecture notes =)